# Dynamical systems with control input

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Please I have been trying to write the mathematical formulation of my nonlinear dynamical system for quite some time and I will appreciate any input.

** Problem Description**

Assuming, I am traveling from Point A to Point B and there are hundred different paths (1 to 100). I do not know the optimum path (path with the shortest distance).

Let's assume again that I have a controller input $u$ representing the different paths. i.e. if $ u = 1$ then the system (me) will travel along path 1.

Let's also assume that the state $x$ of the system is the distance traveled at a given time.

The question is how can one express this dynamical system? Knowing that the control input $u$ is not directly related to the state $x$.

Does it make sense to represent the system described like this:

$$\dot{x} = f(t,x) + g(t,x,u)$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure it would be in continues time and not discrete time? And if there are a finite number of paths, can't you try all and see which is best?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @KwinvanderVeen. Assuming I am traveling from point A to B at a uniform speed, my state (distance traveled) will be in continuous time. However, the finite path can be in discrete time. This could lead to some kind of Hybrid dynamical system. In reality, I do not know the number of paths and to make matters worse, the path is time-varying. So it may not be possibe to try the paths one after the other. I will really appreciate more feedback.

Comment: Then could you update question? Namely, your problem description currently is too vague and is impossible to answer. Are you maybe considering a mobile robot transversing some kind of maze?

Comment: What happens if you change $u$ from $1$ to $2$ for example during the traveling (i.e. while you are between A and B)?

Comment: @SampleTime thank you for the feedback. Great question. I have never thought about this question and thanks for asking. Let's assume that one can change the travel path instantaneously. (i.e. you can move from PATH 1 to PATH 2) any time.

Comment: @Tee Changing instantaneously from one path to another does not make much sense physically, unless you are on a graph and can choose the next path every time you reach a node.

Comment: @KBS thanks for the feedback. I totally agree with you. I am still at the early stage of my work, and I have made that assumption for simplicity. I have plans to develop a detailed model for my system, where I will account for the time the object moves from state one to two.

Comment: @Tee In the end you may need to model that over a graph on which you will travel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my current understanding of the problem, I would represent the system as a hybrid system of the form
$$\dot{x}(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
v,&& \mathrm{if\ }x(t)\le f(u)\\
0,&& \mathrm{if\ }x(t)>f(u)\\
\end{array}\right.$$

where $x(t)$, as required, represents the distance traveled from point A at time $t$ and $v>0$ is the traveling speed which I assume here to be constant.

The function $f:U\mapsto\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ is a function that maps the input $u$ to the total traveling distance from $A$ to $B$ using path $u\in U=\{1,\ldots\}$. I am also assuming here that once a path has been chosen, then we are not allowed to change; i.e. $u$ is constant.

Basically, what the system is describing is 1) traveling at constant speed $v$ until we reach the destination and 2) once B is reached, we just stop.

This answer is based on my current understanding of the problem and I will be happy to update it in case there is something that I misunderstood. I have other, more complex, solutions that can capture more complex behaviors but I wanted to provide the simplest one.

Edit. If the speed is time-varying and also path-dependent, then you can consider the following model
$$\dot{x}(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
v_u(t),&& \mathrm{if\ }x(t)\le f(u)\\
0,&& \mathrm{if\ }x(t)>f(u)\\
\end{array}\right.$$
where $v_u(t)$ is now the input/path-dependent time-varying velocity. Here again, path is chosen at the beginning and remains the same until reaching the final destination.

Comment: Thank you very much for this feedback @KBS. Your understanding of the problem is correct. I have never thought about modeling the problem as a hybrid system up until now.  Please how will the formulation change if (1) The velocity of the object is a function of the path $ u \in U = {1, 2, ....}$ and (2) The velocity is time-varying.  Thank you so much for your inputs..

Comment: @Tee I have updated my answer.